# _AssertionError ('package:firebase_storage/src/reference.dart': Failed assertion: line 127 pos 12: 'file.absolute.existsSync()': is not true

Tags: flutter

I get this error when I try to change Mediafile type to file type and try to upload mediafiles to firebase storage,
Here is my code that change Mediafile to file type

```
  File file = File(selectedMedias[i].toString()); // Convert MediaFile to File
  String url = await uploadFile(file); // Upload the File to Firebase Storage
  downloadUrls.add(url);
  if (i == selectedMedias.length - 1) {
    Storytask(user?.uid ?? '', user?.photoUrl ?? '', user?.username ?? '');
  }
```

### Here is the code that I upload file to firebase

```
Future<String> uploadFile(File file) async {
  final metaData = SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg');
  final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
  Reference ref =
      storageRef.child('pictures/${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch}.jpg');
  final uploadTask = ref.putFile(file as File);

  final taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
  String url = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  return url;
}
```